# How to run a code when a Laravel Job try is killed by timeout (Horizon)

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

I created a Laravel Job with 3 tries and timeout after 10 minutes. I am using Horizon.

I can handle the failure after 3 tries using the method `failed`, but how can I handle the timeout event each 3 tries of this job ?

Used for logging and feedback, I want my user to be notified when the first or second try fails and it will be retried later.

```php
class MyJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $tries = 3;
    public $timeout = 600;
    
    // [...]

    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        // The failure of the 3 tries.
    }

    // Any method for catching each timeouts ?
}
```

Comment: I'm not really following what you are trying to do. Do you want to distinct a job that's failing between a timeout and an error?

Comment: Or do you want to catch a job exceeding the timeout limit every time the job is being run (each try)?

Comment: The second option, to catch each time a job timeout (so 3 events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

**TLDR;**

Put a `pcntl_signal` at the beginning of your your job `handle()` and then you can do something like call a `onTimeout()` method :

```php
public function handle()
{
    pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, function () {
        $this->onTimeout();
        exit;
    });

    // [...]
}

public function onTimeout()
{
    // This method will be called each
}
```

**The story behind :**

The [Queue documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#timeout) says : `The pcntl PHP extension must be installed in order to specify job timeouts.`

So, digging into the [pcntl PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.pcntl.php) I found interesting `pcntl_*` functions. And a call of `pcntl_signal` into [Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php l221](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L211).

It looks that if we register a method using `pcntl_signal` it replace the previous handler. I tried to load the Laravel one using `pcntl_signal_get_handler` but I can't manage to call it. So the workaroud is to call `exit;` so Laravel will consider the process as lost and mark it as timeout (?). There is the 3 tries, the retry_after is respected, and at the last try the job fails ... It may be cleaner to keep the original handler, but as it work well on my case so I will stop investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> You may define the $failOnTimeout property on the job class

```
/**
 * Indicate if the job should be marked as failed on timeout.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $failOnTimeout = true;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#failing-on-timeout

Comment: No, this is only feasible if you explicitly want to mark a job as failed even if it has 2 tries left. This can cause a lot of unusual results. Only because a job reaches a time limit, doesn‘t mean it failed.

Comment: But interesting would be the fact if the failed event could distinguish the timeout event given as an argument, if so, you could, in the callback of the failed event, mark the job as a timeout, and continue as usual

Comment: Indeed this option mark the job as failed at the first timeout, and skip the two other tries :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a method for that,

But you can do something like catch the Error thrown if the job fails and verify that its from timeout exception which I believe would throw the exception handler `Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException`.

Something like;

```
public function handle() {
    try {
        // run job
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {   

        // manually fail it if attempt is more than twice
        if ($this->attempts() > 2)             
            $this->fail($exception);

        // Check if the error it timeout related
        if ( $exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException ) {
            // Whatever you want to do when it fails due to timeout
        }
        
        // release the job back to queue after 5 seconds
        $this->release(5);
        return;
    }
}
```

Just try running a job and make sure it fails because of timeout, to verify the actual timeout class exception

Comment: I tried your solution with a `sleep();` inside the try block and no exception was thrown (
even dumping just after the catch ...) I wonder if the `kill` instruction sent by Horizon is outside the PHP Process (something like a linux `kill`, so no exception is thrown inside the process ?)

Comment: ah, I forgot to consider you are using horizon, Im not very familiar with redis connection, but you should double check what are the actual exception thrown in there when the job fails

Comment: also check the `exception` data in `failed_jobs` table when the job is marked as failed, and you should set the `$failOnTimeout` to `true` to capture the actual exception instead of `MaxAttempt` exception